# Upload Excel document to shared folder on Google Drive with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have found different scripts for Java, C#, and Access VBA for uploading a file to Google Drive. But the only thing I have found with Excel VBA, is a script saving the file in your local Google Drive folder and then wait for the application to sync it.

Is it possible to somehow upload the Excel file directly to a folder that has been shared with me? If yes, how?

Comment: can you share the c# / access vba code that you have?

Comment: Excel VBA is not very different from Access VBA, what is not working for you in the access code? Could you post it and give us the errors you get?

Comment: Thanks for you prompt reply. @SiddharthRout I have found this thread with a C# (and VB.net) https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28088849/Uploading-to-Google-Drive-using-VBA-or-VB.html

Comment: @VincentG I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401046/uploading-to-google-drive-using-vba?rq=1 it is not exactly what I had in mind, but I guess the way it connects to Gdrive could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to do this.

First, you need to create credentials. Follow this guide: https://updraftplus.com/support/configuring-google-drive-api-access-in-updraftplus/

- The credentials should be `OAuth Client ID`
- Application Type: Other

Secondly, I downloaded this Access VBA code found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627231/1042624

Afterwards, in the Access document, there will be a settings box. You need to fill in the information about your account and the credentials from step 1 here. Then you can use the upload button, and it will work.
However, if you want to use this in Excel and without the form boxes, then you have to step through the code and find where the settings form boxes´ info are being used. It takes quite a while, and the code is too long to post here. But now you at least have the information on how to do it.

NB: I still did not crack the 2-step verification that I have enabled.